# How do I get the index of the current track being played using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am working on an Android project that involves the use of Google's ExoPlayer.
I have a list of video sources which I build a playlist from using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vidList.length(); i++) {
    MediaSource source = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(vidList.getJSONObject(i).getString("url")),
                                buildDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter), extractorsFactory, mainHandler, HomeFragment.this);
                        mediaSources.add(source);
                        captions.add(vidList.getJSONObject(i).getString("caption"));
                    }

    mediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources.toArray(new MediaSource[mediaSources.size()]));
```

I then call

```
exoplayer.prepare(mediasource, false, false)
```

and the videos play in succession fine. I would like to display the caption of the currently playing video in a textView and so I have a separate list that holds the "caption" values for each video.

From scouring through the code I see that I can get the currently playing video in the playlist like this;

```
exoPlayer.getCurrentPeriodIndex()
```

Which seems to work and returns the index except for one problem. It returns the value of 0 twice as playback starts. That is video at index 0 returns period 0 as well as video at index 1. This only occurs at indexes 0 and 1 and thereafter everything else looks fine except that the getCurrentPeriodIndex() will return theAccurateIndex - 1.

I see this also happening in the demo Exoplayer application.
Is there a better way to determine what track is currently playing in the playlist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

To find the currently playing track, you need to reference `currentWindowIndex` exoPlayer field. Looks like this in Java...

```
exoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex()
```

I'm not sure what `getCurrentPeriodIndex()` does, and the [docs](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#getCurrentPeriodIndex--) don't elaborate, and I don't like speculating.

Comment: in my case both the options are working, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`exoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex()` is Deprecated.

Use `exoPlayer.getCurrentMediaItemIndex()` instead.